# How to check for phase separation in polymer simulations?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, polymers, phase-diagram

Suppose I am running a molecular dynamics simulation of a polymer solution that exhibits upper critical solution temperature. From standard solution thermodynamics, we expect to see a polymer-rich zone and a polymer-lean zone. **How do we spot these in a simulation cell?**

Is it a visual check, or is there analysis one can perform to see this? What are some key methods one employs to check solution phase behavior?

For example, I am told that [PNIPAm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(N-isopropylacrylamide)) exhibits lower critical solution temperature (LCST) above 305 K. I expect the PNIPAm chains to congregate and so on. But my question is, what thermodynamic quantity or correlation should I be on the look out for after I have run this simulation to prove that I am seeing LCST-type phase separation?

Comment: how short are the polymers? if short, for polymers, you may be able to run Gibbs Ensemble Monte Carlo

Comment: @B.Kelly I expect the simulation cell to have something like 10 40-mers?

Comment: David kofke or Peter Cummings may be names worth exploring. I am not sure if they do polymers, but they sure do phase separation and miscibility

Comment: Hi megamance! Were those suggestions by BKelly useful? How are things going with this almost 8-month old question? Please update us!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the best way to spot phase transitions in polymers is to run the extended cell simulations and calculate surface tension, as seen in this paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3227905.